# Get dispatchEvent data as a result

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.6

Here i am working on native extension in which i send/dispatch data in the dataevent like:

```
public static const PASSING_VIDEO_URL : String = "PASSING_URL";
dispatchEvent( new DataEvent( PASSING_URL,true,false,level) );
```

Now on eventlistener

```
cd.addEventListener( CD.PASSING_URL, onURL );

protected function onURL(event:Event):void
{
    txtUrl.text = event.data;
    txtUrl.text = event.text;
}
```

I got that data on `event.data` when i watch. but i write as above. `event.data;` Or `event.text;` then i am getting error.

So, my question is how can i get `event.data` or `event.text` ?

Comment: What error do you receive? Are you aware that your second line overrides whatever the first one does?

Comment: use metadata to declare what events a class can dispatch, most code editor will then be able to implement listeners with the correct signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.data`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/DataEvent.html#data) property is defined in [`DataEvent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/DataEvent.html), **not** [`Event`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html). But your parameter of the method is of type `Event`.

Change the type of the parameter to `DataEvent`.